# Protocol not available errors in squid3

Tags: proxy, cache, squid, log-files

I set up a transparent cache proxy on my Raspberry Pi with Squid3. Everything seems to be working fine and Squid is caching everything it's supposed to and working perfectly. The cache.log is filled with this:

```
IpIntercept.cc(137) NetfilterInterception:  NF getsockopt(SO_ORIGINAL_DST) failed on FD 17: (92) Protocol not available
```

I can't figure out why that's there and what's wrong since the cache is working fine, but it's clogging my log file.

Comment: Maybe you have a client that uses `explicit` proxy while your `squid` config listens on the same port for `explicit` and `transparent`, or you redirect both on the same port

Comment: @krisFR Hmm maybe. All I have it listening for is transparent on 3129, but maybe I should specify something for explicit too.